# Magento cart price rule not applied free shipping to whole cart in magento2.4.5-p1

Tags: shopping-cart-price-rules, magento2.4.5p1

**How to reproduce this issue**:

**Make a cart price rule**:
With **no coupon code** and Free shipping option select to "**For shipment with matching items**"
[image: cart price rule with no coupon code]

**On frontend Shipping price should be zero**
[image]

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Comment: Same issue present in 2.4.5-p2

Answer (score 0):

Please elaborate on your query more. The items you select in **"For shipment with matching items"** may not fit your criteria.

Steps To Reproduce

- Check your coupon code configuration again
- Check the items that you select again
- Check on the shopping site that you added to the cart
- Check the priority of the coupon code if some other coupon code is already applied.
- Debug the shipping methods how you configured it.